# Wordpress DB password: how to obtain dynamically instead of hardcoding in wp-config.php

Tags: mysql, wordpress, security

We need to retrieve the database password from a secured source instead of hardcoding in wp-config.php. I can always call our API from wp-includes/load.php:require_wp_db() and use instead of DB_PASSWORD but thought there will be a better way than changing core WP files. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about retrieving the password from a ENV variable? would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just some random ideas i have had right now:

- Create an API REST in another server storing the database password. As parameter you will pass a db instance name and the ip from the source you already have.

Then implement a lookup into the rest api like that.

IP      | db_intance  | password

x.x.x.x | db_wordpress | password1

y.y.y.y | db_wordpress_site2 | password2

You need to make the api only respond to the right combination of source ip address and db_instance.

Make this api call only one time at startup of site and store it inside a PHP variable, if it returns authentication error in mysql then you request it again.